# Why should I make an instance of the View class?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, onclick

This code sums 2 numbers.

My question is: why should I make an instance `v` of the class `View`, if I will never use it in my code?
If I try without the instance `v` of the class `View`, the app crashes.

```
  public void  onButtonClick(View v) {
         EditText r1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
         EditText r2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
         TextView t  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
         int num1 = Integer.parseInt(r1.getText().toString());
         int num2 = Integer.parseInt(r2.getText().toString());
         int sum = num1+num2;
         t.setText(Integer.toString(sum));

    }
```

Comment: please post your layout file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's the required method signature for when you add an `onClick` listener in an xml layout.

The object variable `v` is used in case you have multiple Views firing to the same method when clicked.

You can then use `v.getId()` to determine **which** View fired the method (normally, by using a `switch ... case`) and act consequently.